# How to update a custbody value in netsuite from a nlapiSearchRecord

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to update a custbody field from a bill. The script is a webhook that receives information when a payment was successfully, so when the invoice_id is sent via the webhook, the system search for the invoice information. At that point is when i need to update a field to set it as "Paid". My code is like the following;

```
var netsuiteInformation = nlapiSearchRecord('vendorbill', null, filters, columns);

markInvoiceAsPaid(netsuiteInformation, foo)

function markInvoiceAsPaid(infoDocNetsuite, data) {
    var status = infoDocNetsuite[0].getValue('custbody_payment_status');
    infoDocNetsuite[0].nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_payment_status', 3);
    infoDocNetsuite[0].nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_reject_reason', data.reasonDescription);
}
```

The search is being performed without problems, but when i try to do an update using `nlapiSetFieldValue` or `setFieldValue` im getting an error from netsuite like this one:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function nlapiSetFieldValue in object nlobjSearchResult. (cancelPaymentWebhook.js$4053079#30)
```

So i dont know how to make the update. Do you know how to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to load the particular record in search then set the field value in the record object then also save the record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nlapiSetFieldValue isn't a member of the search result object. You can just call the function directly if this is a client script or if it's a user event or otherwise you will need to load a record using `nlapiLoadRecord(type, id)` and update it with `recordObj.setFieldValue(fieldId, value)`

```js
var netsuiteInformation = nlapiSearchRecord('vendorbill', null, filters, columns);

markInvoiceAsPaid(netsuiteInformation, foo)

function markInvoiceAsPaid(infoDocNetsuite, data) {
    var status = infoDocNetsuite[0].getValue('custbody_payment_status');
    nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_payment_status', 3);
    nlapiSetFieldValue('custbody_reject_reason', data.reasonDescription);
}
```